# Quadruple precision in G++ 4.6.3 Linux using quadmath

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, quadruple-precision

I've tried to execute the code

```
#include <quadmath.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  char* y = new char[1000];
  quadmath_snprintf(y, 1000, "%Qf", 1.0q);
  std::cout << y << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

with this command

```
g++ test.cpp -o test
```

But I got the error:

```
/tmp/cctqto7E.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `quadmath_snprintf(char*, unsigned int, char const*, ...)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The version is:

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see the same behaviour:

```
~/coding/q$ g++ test.cpp -lquadmath
/tmp/ccYdHwL5.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `quadmath_snprintf(char*, unsigned int, char const*, ...)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

One workaround is to include the header using this pattern instead:

```
extern "C" {
#include "quadmath.h"
}
```

after which:

```
~/coding/q$ g++ test.cpp -lquadmath
~/coding/q$ ./a.out 
1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks. It works for me.[code]  `g++ test.cpp -o test -lquadmath  
./test  
1.000000`

Comment: I am using GCC 5.3.0 and this workaround does not work.

Comment: this worked for me, and adding the option -lquadmath to the gcc command got my C programs to work as well.

Comment: where do you include `extern "C" {
#include "quadmath.h"
}` can you please provide more details in your answer? Thanks